# Who is the man placing the dead deer?

Tags: the-walking-dead

In season 3 episode 4, at the beginning of the episode,

> we see a man placing a dead deer near the prison,
>  and lures some zombies inside the prison.
>  But we never see that man's face.

So who is that man?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Obviously spoilers below.

In the very same episode, it's revealed to be [Andrew](http://walkingdead.wikia.com/wiki/Andrew_%28TV_Series%29). In the previous episode, he was let out to be eaten by zombies, but he somehow survived. It's also a mystery how he was able to kill a deer during that time....

Anyway, from early in the episode we see a man that planted the deer carcass run from the scene and open the gates for the zombies to get in.

[image: A man that planted the deer carcass runs away with an axe]

Later on in the episode, we see Andrew attack Rick with that same axe.

[image: That same man attacks Rick]

Comment: ahh thanks, that clears up alot :)

Comment: Walking Dead is filmed here in Atlanta...trust me, there's plenty of deer around even after a zombie apocalypse :-D